# Paragraph <p> alert box as echo?

Tags: php, css, html, paragraph

```
<p class="alert-danger"><strong>Achtung!</strong> This alert box indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.<span class="alert-danger-closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span></p>
```

so I have created my own alert box but the problem is that it doesn't work with php, can you help me?

Comment: Could you share a bit more of your code related to your alert box, like the php setting your alert box. And explain more what does't work and eventually how it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take some time to learn PHP syntax, this is a pretty obvious solution. You need to escape or change the quotes.

Escaping:

```
echo "<p class=\"alert-danger\"><strong>DANGER!</strong> This alert box indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.<span class=\"alert-danger-closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">&times;</span></p>";
```

Change the quotes (have to escape the single quotes still):

```
 echo '<p class="alert-danger"><strong>DANGER!</strong> This alert box indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.<span class="alert-danger-closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\';">&times;</span></p>';
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then please mark it as such by clicking the green check mark below the voting buttons on my answer.

Comment: echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\"><strong>Success!</strong>Registration successful, please check your email to activate your acount.</div>";    know I have the problem with the div, there is no output...